# Dagger 2 injection of recreated module

Tags: dagger-2

I have NameComponent and NameModule. Also I have list of names. When user select one of item in list I create new NameModule.

In my Application class I have following code:

```
public NameComponent createNameComponent(String name) {
nameComponent = DaggerNameComponent
    .nameModule(new NameModule(name))
    .build();

return nameComponent;
```

}

I have textView with a current selected name Name1. 
name field is injected. 
When user select name Name2 in list I need refresh so I do this:

```
textView.setText(name);
```

but it does not refresh name.

My question is how to force to inject field on module change? Do I have to recreate Activity every time when I change module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the component returned by the second call to `createNameComponent` is different from first one, you need to call `component.inject(this)` every time.

Comment: I had first had to component.inject(this) , then textView.setText(name);

Comment: yes, you need to do both. glad you solved the issue:)